# web animations api, resetting 1st animation at end of chain

Tags: javascript, animation, web-animations-api

I'm experimenting with the web animations API for the first time, and trying to chain some values together. I'm a little confused as for this simple animation, where it will translate 200px along the X axis, then 200px down along the Y axis once the first animation is complete.

However, at the end of the animation, it resets the X value of the initial animation. I've tried playing around with `'both' | 'forwards'` for the fill mode property, as well as setting translateX to 0/200 in the second transform declaration. Feel like I'm missing something quite simple here.

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box');
const animateRight = box.animate(
    [{ transform: 'translateX(0)' }, { transform: 'translateX(200px)' }],
    {
        fill: 'forwards',
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        duration: 2000,
    }
);
animateRight.finished.then(() => {
    box.animate([{ transform: 'translateY(0)' }, { transform: 'translateY(100px)' }], {
        composite: 'add',
        fill: 'both',
        duration: 1500,
    });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm stuck with the same issue as well!

Answer (score 1):

Once the first animation finishes, it remains active because of `fill: 'forwards'`. Then you performed your second animation where you moved the box downwards. Here's where the problem starts: Naturally, you can't actually have 2 separate `transform`s on the same element's style since it's just a single property, so what's *really* happening is that once the second animation starts, the first `transform` is overwritten. The only reason the box is still to the right during the second animation is because of `composite: add`—it sort of kept that X displacement, if that makes sense.

But then as soon as the second animation actually completes, the animation of course ceases, but because of the `fill: 'both'` (which could have also been `fill: 'forwards'`—that makes no difference here), you keep the result of the keyframes you specified for the second animation, which is simply translating Y from 0 to 100 and nothing about X.

There are 2 ways you can fix the example in this specific question. The first involves using `commitStyles()`, and the second involves using the new individual transform properties available in CSS (and consequently WAAPI).

***Solution 1: Use commitStyles()***

The simplest solution would be to call `commitStyles()` on the first animation right after it finishes. This will apply the effects of the X translation to the element's actual inline style, so when the first animation finishes, it essentially "saves" that transform style.

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box');
const animateRight = box.animate(
    [{ transform: 'translateX(0)' }, { transform: 'translateX(200px)' }],
    {
        fill: 'forwards',
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        duration: 2000,
    }
);
animateRight.finished.then(() => {
  animateRight.commitStyles();
    box.animate([{ transform: 'translateY(0)' }, { transform: 'translateY(100px)' }], {
        composite: 'add',
        fill: 'forwards',
        duration: 1500,
    })
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

This approach could be a little janky because of the current issues surrounding `fill` and the potential of doubling the effect of an animation once `commitStyles()` is called, but that's beyond the scope of this discussion. If you run into issues like that, you can solve them by setting `fill` to `none` *immediately after* calling `commitStyles()`. Example:

```
someAnimation.commitStyles();
someAnimation.effect?.updateTiming({ fill: 'none' });
```

***Solution 2: Use `translate` instead of `transform`***

In CSS, you can now actually individually set `translate`, `rotate`, and `scale` separately. For example, the following are equivalent:

```
.thing {
   transform: translate(500px, 200px);
}
.thing2 {
  translate: 500px 200px;
}
```

Naturally, this means you can set those properties using WAAPI as well. Since they are obviously different properties from `transform`, you can even use them at the same time. You could have `translate`, `scale`, `rotate`, and `transform` all acting on the same element at the same time. I removed the `composite` property in this example to prove this.

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box');
const animateRight = box.animate(
    [{ translate: '0' }, { translate: '200px' }],
    {
        fill: 'forwards',
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        duration: 2000,
    }
);
animateRight.finished.then(() => {
    box.animate([{ transform: 'translateY(0)' }, { transform: 'translateY(100px)' }], {
        fill: 'forwards',
        duration: 1500,
    });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Combined with `commitStyles()` and `composite: add` (or `composite: accumulate`), the individual  transform properties can be extremely powerful in general.

Comment: You may want to move your answer to the duplicate target (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74769431/stack-add-composite-accumulate-multiple-transform-translate-animations-in-the-we/) with a little edit to match that question. My accepted answer there was already pointing to `commitStyles`, but the addition on `translate:` is probably valuable there.

Comment: @Kaiido I see. I'll get around to that when I have time—thanks.