# stack/add/composite/accumulate multiple transform=translate animations in the Web Animation API

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, svg-animate, web-animations-api

*I have been running around in circles*

I use the Web Animation API `transform:translate()` to make my *player* run around the bases.

`runto("first").then(() => runto("second"));` does the **correct** animation,
**but then deletes the first/previous `translate` to *first base***,
thus my *player* ends up in the wrong location

[image]

I have tried every combination of

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyframeEffect/composite
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyframeEffect/iterationComposite

**Is it at all possible to preserve all the translates on one element?**

JSFiddle playground: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/8df2qsop/

---

```js
  let field = document.getElementById("FIELD");
  let player = field.getElementById("player");
  function getCenter(el , { left, top, width, height } = el.getBoundingClientRect()) {
    let point = Object.assign(field.createSVGPoint(),{  x : left + width / 2, y : top + height / 2 }).matrixTransform(field.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    return { cx:~~point.x, cy:~~point.y };
  }
  function runto(destination) {
    let {cx:playerX,cy:playerY} = getCenter(player);
    let {cx:baseX  ,cy:baseY  } = getCenter(field.getElementById(destination));
    let translateX = baseX - playerX;  
    let translateY = baseY- playerY;
    let track = `<line x1="${playerX}" y1="${playerY}" x2="${baseX}" y2="${baseY}" stroke-width="10" stroke="black"/>`;
    field.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",track);
    return player.animate([{ 
          //transform: `translate(${0}px,${0}px)` 
          }, { transform: `translate(${translateX}px,${translateY}px)` }], 
        { duration:500, fill:"forwards", composite:"add" }
    ).finished; // return Promise
  }
  runto("first").then(() => runto("second"));
```

```html
<style>
  #FIELD { background: lightgreen; width: 150px; margin: 20px }
</style>
<svg id=FIELD viewBox="0 0 250 250" transform="rotate(45)">
  <g fill="brown">
    <path id="home"   d="M 150 150 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z" fill="green"/>
    <path id="first"  d="M 150 20  h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z"/>
    <path id="second" d="M  20 20  h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z"/>
    <path id="third"  d="M 20 150  h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z"/>
  </g>
  <circle id="player" cx="190" cy="190" r="30" fill="gold"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call [`Animation#commitStyles()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/commitStyles) after the animation completes, so that its state is "written" to your player.
You now need to come back to the default `composite: "replace"` option, and you also need to modify your initial player settings so that it's positioned using CSS `translate()` instead of using its `cx` and `cy` values (or you could also modify your calculations so they return relative positions instead).

```js
let field = document.getElementById("FIELD");
let player = field.getElementById("player");

function getCenter(el, { left, top, width, height } = el.getBoundingClientRect()) {
  let point = Object.assign(field.createSVGPoint(), {
    x: left + width / 2,
    y: top + height / 2
  }).matrixTransform(field.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  return {
    cx: ~~point.x,
    cy: ~~point.y
  };
}

async function runto(destination) {
  let { cx: playerX, cy: playerY } = getCenter(player);
  let { cx: baseX, cy: baseY } = getCenter(field.getElementById(destination));
  let translateX = baseX - playerX;
  let translateY = baseY - playerY;
  let track = `<line x1="${playerX}" y1="${playerY}" x2="${baseX}" y2="${baseY}" stroke-width="10" stroke="black"/>`;
  field.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", track);
  const anim = player.animate([{
    transform: `translate(${baseX}px,${baseY}px)`
  }], {
    duration: 500,
    fill: "forwards"
  });
  await anim.finished;
  anim.commitStyles(); // write the current state to the animated element
  anim.cancel(); // no need to keep it around anymore
}
runto("first").then(() => runto("second"));
```

```html
<style>
  #FIELD {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px
  }
</style>
<svg id=FIELD viewBox="0 0 250 250" transform="rotate(45)">
  <g fill="brown">
    <path id="home"   d="M 150 150 h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z" fill="green"/>
    <path id="first"  d="M 150 20  h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z"/>
    <path id="second" d="M  20 20  h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z"/>
    <path id="third"  d="M 20 150  h 80 v 80 h -80 v -80z"/>
  </g>
  <circle id="player" cx="0" cy="0" r="30" style="transform:translate(190px, 190px)" fill="gold"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: cool; saves me storing previousTranslates, and reducing it to the net translate